# Google Map Api for municipality and wards?

Tags: google-maps

Is there any Google map API for particular municipality and wards. Any reference could be appreciate. Can i get the border for municipality and wards.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to put an outline on the map that defines an area, in your case the municipal and ward areas

I know in the United States there is Census data that has the longitude and latitudes of all of the counties that are available for download for free. I am not sure if the country you want to show boundaries on has something similar however a Google search for "long lat coordinates outline Berlin municipal" reveals lots of results.

So what do you do with the coordinates after you find them - Google Maps API allows you put Polygons on the map based on geo-coordinates.

I use the Google Encoded Polylines part of the Geometry library to store my polygons and then redisplay them when a specific state is being displayed.

Example

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googlemap"), myOptions);
var encodedpoints = "<encoded points string>";

var polyOptions = {
"strokeColor": '#000000',
"strokeOpacity": 1,
"strokeWeight": 1,
"fillColor": "#000000",
"fillOpacity": 0.5
};
polyOptions.path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encodedpoints)
var mypolygon = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
mypolygon.setMap(map);
```

This example will put a polygon on the map that has a black line border and 50% opacity black fill. You can change the options to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to study this one.. This might be helpful

https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&t=m&source=embed&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=206991552322184464231.0004b92f102c33413c51a

Answer (score 0):

Google does have a [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) that might be of use to you. It allows you to look up information on virtually every kind of place - including municipalities. I don't know if it will give you the bounds you need to draw a polygon onto the map, but at the very least if will give you a starting point.

As for actually drawing the bounds onto the map, you can use [overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays)

Answer (score 0):

I just came across an API by [govtrack.us](http://gis.govtrack.us/map/demo/dc-ward-2013/) for all sorts of government boundaries, including DC Ward.

to get all the boundaries:

```
http://gis.govtrack.us/boundaries/dc-ward-2013/shape?format=json
```

to get a single ward:

```
http://gis.govtrack.us/boundaries/dc-ward-2013/5/shape?format=json
```